# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key bug?

Tags: xcode, swift, tableview, xcode7

I just updated to Xcode 7 and I'm not sure if I'm making an error or encountering a bug. I'm trying to add an outlet for a table view but the app crashes every time! I've done this several times in the past before with no problem until now!

This is what I see:

[image]

Readout of console:

```
2015-10-01 12:30:16.805 edus[74179:1614535] Unknown class     _TtC4edus25SelectClassViewController in Interface Builder file.
2015-10-01 12:30:16.807 edus[74179:1614535] Unknown class     _TtC4edus25SelectClassViewController in Interface Builder file.
2015-10-01 12:30:16.817 edus[74179:1614535] *** Terminating app due to  uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController     0x7fa3aaf51ef0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableView.'
```

--EDIT--
I don't even think xcode is reading the view controller. I looked at the source code for the storyboard and the view controller in question is not even present.

Also Xcode is telling me that the view controller file has been moved "A+" even though I have done nothing to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted it appears that you have not properly set the class of the view controller in the Storyboard.  If you select the orange icon in the header of the scene you're trying to connect an outlet in, and click on the third tab in the inspector area (or command-option-3), what is filled in for the Class field under Custom Class?  I am guessing it is empty and defaulting to UIViewController, there is a typo, or the value of the Module field is incorrect (which happens if you type the name of the class prior to creating the class).

Comment: Thanks for the response...unfortunately everything was inputted correctly. I solved this problem by updating to El Capitan and reinstalling xcode...

Comment: @MichaelNinh are you kidding me ? re-installing the OS. ? I have the same issue, my IBOutlets connections are perfectly well. Although the Custom class module is set to None, but absolutely all my projects have that value set to None.. so I dont see why it shouldnt work.